# jQuery show div with same class as selected dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a dropdown:

```
<select class="select_menu_type">
    <option value="value1">foo</option>
    <option value="value2">bar</option>
</select>

<div class="value1">Lorem ipsum VALUE1</div>
<div class="value2">Lorem ipsum VALUE2</div>
```

All div's are display none by default.
I need to display the div with same class as selected option value.

**Any idea how to do this using jQuery?**

My progress so far:

```
jQuery('#select_order_type').change(function(){
  var selectedOption = document.getElementById('select_order_type');
  console.log(selectedOption.options[selectedOption.selectedIndex].value)
});
```

I need show div with same class as my selected value...

Comment: Also, I recommend uses IDs instead of classes for the divs - IDs are one-time-use, classes are for multiple use. Unless I'm assuming incorrectly, it seems like this setup only occurs once on the page.

Comment: use the search button and try searching `.load()` function and `onchange` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
$('.select_menu_type ').change(function(){
    var $Select = $(this).val();
    $('div').hide();
    $('.'+$Select).show();

})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/F6TRY/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
   $('.select_menu_type').on('change',function() {
        var cls = this.value;
        $('div').hide();
        $('div.' + cls).show();
    });
});
```

For better coding I would suggest enclosing the div elements in another div or element so that it will be easier to control just those divs.

Answer (score 0):

i already tried it on my own i hope it is the answer for your question :)

First onloading of document we need to get how many options you have in your select and we should hide all the div then show the div that have class equals to the selected value of select box

```
var optionValues = [];
$('.select_menu_type option').each(function() {
    optionValues.push($(this).val());
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    for( var ctr = 0; ctr < optionValues.length; ctr++){
        if( $('.select_menu_type').val() === optionValues[ctr]){
            $('.'+optionValues[ctr]).show();
        }
        else{
            $('.'+optionValues[ctr]).hide();
        }
    }
});
```

then just copy the ready function inside onchange of that select :)

```
$('.select_menu_type').change(function(){
    for( var ctr = 0; ctr < optionValues.length; ctr++){
        if( $('.select_menu_type').val() === optionValues[ctr]){
            $('.'+optionValues[ctr]).show();
        }
        else{
            $('.'+optionValues[ctr]).hide();
        }
    }
});
```